# WP8 - How do I add a share menu?

Tags: windows-phone-8, menu, share

I was just wondering if there was any way to add a share menu like this: http://puu.sh/5XkRD.jpg

Basically i need it in a way that once the user clicks on the "Share..." menu item in the context menu, the user will be navigated to that share menu where he can select a method to share.

Is anyone able to help me with this?

Answer (score 3):

Use **`ShareStatusTask`**: [How to use the share status task for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394027%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

> Use the share status task to enable the user to share a status message on the social network of their choice.

Sample code:

```
ShareStatusTask shareStatusTask = new ShareStatusTask();
shareStatusTask.Status = "I'm developing a Windows Phone application!";
shareStatusTask.Show();
```

There is also **`ShareLinkTask`** for sharing links: [How to use the share link task for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394009%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

> Use the share link task to enable the user to share a link on the social network of their choice.

Sample code:

```
ShareLinkTask shareLinkTask = new ShareLinkTask();

shareLinkTask.Title = "Code Samples";
shareLinkTask.LinkUri = new Uri("http://code.msdn.com/wpapps", UriKind.Absolute);
shareLinkTask.Message = "Here are some great code samples for Windows Phone.";

shareLinkTask.Show();
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the first one! The sharestatus but is there a way that when i click Share it will bring it with an option to show Email, Messaging and Facebook?

Comment: I know nothing about that (what doesn't mean it does not exist ;)). You can write it by yourself. There are `SmsComposeTask` and `EmailComposeTask` you can use when user clicks an item on the list.

Comment: Alright. I guess I'll have to make my own control :) thanks for your help.